# SetThreadAffinityMask has no effect

Tags: c++, windows, setthreadaffinitymask

I want a test program only run on cpu1 ,so i write the code like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

    int main(){
        ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentProcess(),1);
        while(1)
          ;
       return 0;
    }
```

but when I open the task manager, I find CPU1 is not full used, and the percent of it's usage is always changing.Why?CPU1 should be 100 percent usage?
sorry to my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetThreadAffinityMask` sets the affinity of a THREAD not of the whole process. If you check the return value you should see that `SetThreadAffinityMask` is failing. To get the current thread use `GetCurrentThread()` not `GetCurrentProcess()`.

i.e. change your code to

```
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(),1)
```

If you want to set the affinity of the whole process use

```
SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(),1)
```